# Problems with Facebook comment plugin when use htaccess

Tags: facebook, mod-rewrite, facebook-javascript-sdk

The facebook comment plugin in my PHP site doesn't understand the URL in the href attrib and displays `Warning: Link us unreachable.`
I have tested with a file that doesn't use .htaccess which runs good and doesn't throw any errors or warnings, but when I put a virtual URL on href. Facebook doesn't understand the url.

This is the code of my site:

```
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {

      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";

      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><fb:comments href="<?php echo $commenturl; ?>"  num_posts="10" width="700"></fb:comments>
```

This is information in my site:

$commenturl = http://smashlix.com/battle/Ipad-or-Windows-8

.htaccess content:  RewriteRule ^battle/(.*)$ ./index.php?view=bd&title=$1

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Your server responds with a 302 and a Location header, and an invalid one at that, because it does not contain a fully qualified URL: http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://smashlix.com/battle/Ipad-or-Windows-8

```
RewriteRule ^battle/(.*)$ ./index.php?view=bd&title=$1
```

Why is there a ./ before the file name? Where is that .htaccess file located, and what’s the RewriteBase?

Comment: because u just begin programing with php, and first use htaccess.
You can explain for me more, Please.This is full my htacess file :

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On 

DirectoryIndex comingsoon.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^battle/(.*)$ ./index.php?view=bd&title=$1

How to facebook comment understand virture URL on href. Please help me ! Thanks a lot.